# What statistics can I apply to explain how much socio demographics influence revenue?

Tags: logistic, random-forest, marketing

I'm looking to explain the revenue made by a coffee shop based on socio demographic data like `gender`, `population`, `education` and `stores nearby`. I've seen that by applying a logistic regression to revenue using those as explanatory variables could work but I don't finalize to understand how it is that I can give out  number and compare each one of those variables to say which generates more revenue, could I apply a logistic regression to explain how much influence each one of variables selected have? And how? Also seen that Random Forest might be useful for it but I don't finish to get what it is and how can I apply it in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things...

a) Why are you using logistic regression?  Revenue is continuous and bounded below by 0, where as logistic regression is for binary outcomes.

b) It sounds like you are interested more by inference than prediction, so random forest -- though good at prediction -- really isn't what you want here.

My advice is to use something like a generalized linear model.  I've seen Gamma regression used frequently to model financial problems, so that might be a first step.

Comment: a) Because I saw a couple of tutorials make it dichotomic, as saying more than 50 grand or less. But I actually want to keep it continuous. b) Yes indeed, I just want to know which demographic aspects influence more on final revenues for the shop. Gamma makes the best sense but `glm` library is not available for  R-Studio 3.6, so it turns into a stack overflow question. Thanks!

Comment: Would a single desition tree make sense also?

Comment: Decision trees are nice because they are interpretable. You lose the ability to make confidence intervals though.